# Add number + varchar to get string concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I add 5596 + 00003  to get 559600003 in SQL Server?

I tried with the following query:

```
select 5596 + '00003'
```

But it is giving 5599 and I want this to show 559600003.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server attempts to return the result in the datatype of the **first** part of the calculation which in your case is a number. It can happily convert the second part of the calculation into a number, and therefore does so.

To obtain the result you want you must convert the first part of the calculation to a string e.g.

```
select convert(varchar, 5596) + '00003'
```

Note: `convert(varchar,x)` uses a default length of 30 which is probably enough for most numbers.

`CONCAT()`, as in one of the other answers is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(5596, '00003')
```

`CONCAT()` does not require any explicit conversion.

Comment: I prefer this  solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CAST`

```
SELECT CAST(5596 AS varchar) + '00003'; -- return 559600003
```

Because :

- CAST is more easier to read than CONVERT
- CAST is ANSI-SQL compliant : it means that the CAST function can be used by many databases

But in case you have a date type CONVERT is more flexible and contains more options than CAST

For more details take a look : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: What would be the advantage of using `cast` over `convert`?

Comment: First (for me) CAST inis more easier to read than CONVERT and second is ANSI-SQL compliant it means that the CAST function can be used by many databases.
But in case you have a date type CONVERT is more flexible 
and contains more options than CAST (please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: That information is useful enough to put in your answer itself. Its always good to provide additional clarity about why your answer is a good answer.